# why this happen when i declare a WindowsCanvas Class

Tags: java, canvas, vlcj

i am trying to declare a WindowsCanvas but when i declare a WindowsCanvas there is a line that show up in the middle is that ok

[image: picture of the java code]

Answer (score 1):

<s>This effect</s> on most IDEs means that the code you're attempting to use has been *deprecated*. This means that it has been deemed obsolete in a later release, and should no longer be used.

You can still use it, but it is recommended that you move onto the newer class, or the newer method of implementing the same functionality. In this case, the answer can be found in [this discussion](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/160).

Answer (score 0):

That Class have been deprecated and still you can use it.

Interesting thing is there is already a better Class given by your API, So this class has been **[deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)**. Search in that direction rather than adjusting with this.